How to send an email from a sandbox to a gmail mail address?
I have tried many things, but all my attempts fail because each time gmail responds with:

Unauthenticated email from xyzyxz.com is not accepted due to
domain's DMARC policy.

All my email addresses in the sandbox use the xyzyxz.com domain and apparently gmail does not like this being done from a sandbox. In the production org, there is no problem.
I have created a verified Organization Wide Email Address, but that results in the same error. Using a gmail address as an Organization Wide Email Address results in a DKIM error.
I must test some email related functionality involving outgoing email. How can I do that in a sandbox?

Fix your DKIM keys and DMARC policy: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389240&language=en_US&type=1

I am hesitant to add test environment domains to our production keys/policies. I am sure that our mail/network admins will feel the same way. I need to verify the functionality that I built, by inspecting the outgoing mails, seeing what they look like on the receiving end. Clearly gmail is too strict. What other options are there?

You can just forget about using a gmail address these days for this purpose. Or Yahoo. These email providers have implemented DMARC and DKIM and will not accept any mail messages from a Salesforce sandbox.
Unless you make alterations to your (production) DMARC/DKIM settings, which is of course something we'd like to avoid.
A solution: yopmail. That site lets you use a temporary email address. I have tried it as a destination for an email from my sandbox and it works! yopmail reports that the mail is not coming from the domain from which it claims it comes, but it will not block it! It shows the mail, including inline images, which is the thing that I want to test.
Note: I have no links with yopmail, until today I had never even heard of it. There are probably other sites that offer a similar service.

Unless you make alterations to your (production) DMARC/DKIM settings - DKIM keys are per-org.  DMARC is DNS and based on send domains. For our customers we typically implement a separate send domain for all sandboxes with per-org set of DKIM keys. One DMARC policy, two DNS entries for each DKIM keyset.
